# SELECT UNION and JOIN from two tables with column varchar instead int

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, union

In database "prodbase" i have three tables:

Table Products

```
|id  | productname |   productprice  | productsupplierID (int11)  |
+----+-------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |   Shirt     |     20          |         3                  |
|  2 |   Tshirt    |     25          |         5                  |
```

Table Supplier

```
|supplierid (int11)  | suppliername (varchar) |
+--------------------+------------------------+
|  3                 |    CompanyA            |
|  5                 |    CompanyB            |
```

Table Staff

```
|id  |  staffname  |   staffposition   | 
+----+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 |    John     |   sales           |
|  2 |    Megan    |   accounting      |
```

Table Products uses a look-up field from table Supplier: supplierID.

I have created a database View to union table Products and Staff.
with following query.

```
SELECT 'prodbase'.'Products'.'productname' AS 'Product', 'prodbase'.'Products'.'productsupplierID' AS 'Supplier' FROM 'prodbase'.'Products'
UNION
SELECT 'prodbase'.'Staff'.'staffname' AS 'Staff', 'prodbase'.'Staff'.'staffposition' AS 'Position' FROM 'prodbase'.'Staff'
ORDER BY 'Supplier'
DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Query is working, but it displays number (ID) in Supplier column.

```
Product: Shirt  
Staff: John  
Position: sales    
Supplier: 3
```

How to create this UNION query with JOIN, so it displays Suppliername insted of supplierID?
**example of desired output:**

```
Product: Shirt  
Staff: John  
Position: sales  
Supplier: CompanyA
```

Comment: Do you want a 5 row result?

Comment: Yes, can be a 5 row result.

Comment: Can be? When having the given table data?

Comment: In example tables i wrote, there are just 2 rows of data. But tables have much more rows of data, so ive stated limit results with 5 rows: LIMIT 5;
But in this example limit can be 2 rows.

Comment: Isn't `'prodbase'.'Products'.'productsupplierID' AS 'Supplier'` written specifically to give you the `productsupplierID` as `Supplier`? If you join table products on table supplier on `productsupplierID = supplierid` then select `suppliername` as supplier you should get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems you need to sort out to have the data returned the way you want. First, I don't think you need a UNION here. A UNION is when you want to combine multiple queries into one. I think you just simply need to use an INNER JOIN on your data to get the desired output. Speaking of relationships, you are missing an important one. There is no relationship between staff, product and supplier, thusly there is no way to provide the output you desire unless you incorporate a relationship table. I created an example of a conceivable relationship table called Sale which links a staff to a product sold. This is not a perfect example, but it will allow you to actually work with the data. With the relationship table, you can INNER JOIN to get all products sold by staff members, in this simple example.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Products(id INT, productname VARCHAR(50), productprice int, productsupplierID int);
> CREATE TABLE Supplier(supplierid INT, suppliername VARCHAR(50));
> CREATE TABLE Staff(id INT, staffname VARCHAR(50),staffposition VARCHAR(50));
>
> CREATE TABLE Sale(staffid INT, productId INT);
>
> INSERT INTO Products VALUES(1,'Shirt',20,3),(2,'Tshirt',25,5);
> INSERT INTO Supplier VALUES(3,'CompanyA'),(5,'CompanyB');
> INSERT INTO Staff VALUES(1,'John','Sales'),(2,'Megan','Accounting');
>
> INSERT INTO Sale VALUES(1,1);
> ```

> 

> ```
> SELECT
>     Products.productname AS Product,
>     Staff.staffname AS Staff,
>     Staff.staffposition AS Position,    
>     Products.productprice AS Price, 
>     Supplier.suppliername AS Supplier 
> FROM 
>   Sale 
>     INNER JOIN Products ON Products.id=Sale.productId         
>     INNER JOIN Supplier ON Supplier.supplierid=Products.productsupplierID
>     INNER JOIN Staff ON Staff.id = Sale.staffid
> ```

> ```
> Product | Staff | Position | Price | Supplier
> :------ | :---- | :------- | ----: | :-------
> Shirt   | John  | Sales    |    20 | CompanyA
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f5e614e326b1bc6b5c4258d2fc67838)*

Edited - I removed Sale based on comment. I guess you could cross join on staff, however, without a relationship between a product/supplier and staff there is no logical way to lay that data over it.

```
SELECT
    Products.productname AS Product,
    Products.productprice AS Price, 
    Supplier.suppliername AS Supplier 
FROM  
    Products 
    INNER JOIN Supplier ON Supplier.supplierid=Products.productsupplierID
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without creating table Sale? productprice int in table Products can be removed. However this query produces ONLY ONE record row, but there should be TWO.

Comment: @willhelm2 - Yes, I removed the Sale table. The relationship between Product and Supplier is joined in the bottom query. I'm still not sure how staff falls in place here.

Comment: Staff is just an accidental needed table, but since there are no relationships with it its not important. This new edited code is working well. Thank you!